# Apache 2.2 RedirectMatch behaviour in a Directory context?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-alias

What is the URL provided to a `RedirectMatch` in a `Directory` context? Does Apache remove the part of the URL up to the current directory?

For context, I am trying to write a `RedirectMatch` in a directory context, and I want to know if I can anchor the front of the regex without having to include the server name and path, e.g.:

```
RedirectMatch ^/foo/([a-z-]+)$ http://www.example.com/$1
```

This doesn't seem to work for me (neither does `^foo/...`), but if I don't anchor the front, it does. I would like to be able to anchor the front of the regex...

Thanks!